# Is it possible to store user credentials on generated Oracle wallet?

Tags: oci-python-sdk

The OCI Phyton SDK has functions, like GenerateAutonomousDatabaseWalletDetails and generate_autonomous_database_wallet, to generate the database wallet.
Is there any function that allows adding user credentials on the wallet for the available service names? Something similar to what can be done with mkstore and createCredentials option.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no function for adding user credentials.   Perhaps somewhat aside, but the 'user' and 'password' would be specific to the database instance, would have to be pre-created in the database and given access privileges, are not tied to a cloud user identity it any way.  The exception being the ADMIN user, who is both an IAM user and a database user.

The underlying connection APIs expect the 'user' and 'password' of these database users in addition to the TLS credentials and the encryption mechanics it provides.